# How to flatten a data frame in apache spark | Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame :

df1

```
uid  text  frequency
1    a     1
1    b     0
1    c     2
2    a     0
2    b     0
2    c     1
```

I need to flatten it on the basis of uid to :

df2

```
uid  a  b  c
1    1  0  2
2    0  0  1
```

I've worked on similar lines in R but haven't been able to translate it into sql or scala.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: How many possible values would `text` column have? Only three (`a`, `b`, `c`) or more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can group by `uid`, use `text` as a pivot column and sum frequencies:

```
   df1
     .groupBy("uid")
     .pivot("text")
     .sum("frequency").show()
```

Comment: The pivot method was taking too much time to run so on checking the API's I found out, this call might be inefficient. Is there any comparison for efficiency or time taken for pivot